# "tuj antaŭ ol" or "ĵus antaŭ ol"? What should I use when something happened just before an other thing?

Tags: word-choice

I am not sure how to translate

> I understood just before you answered.

I think about

> Mi komprenis tuj antaŭ ol vi respondis.

and

> Mi komprenis ĵus antaŭ ol vi respondis.

*tuj antaŭ ol* and *ĵus antaŭ ol* are both used according to Google. Are they different and which one is better?

Answer (score 5):

Normale oni uzas "tuj antaŭ (ol)" en tiaj okazoj. Sed tia uzo ne estas bone klarigita en PMEG (mi provos aldoni ion pri tia uzo), nek en PIV.

"Ĵus" estus erara. "Ĵus" signifas nur "antaŭ momento". "Ĵus antaŭ ol" do signifus "antaŭ momento antaŭ ol", kio donas tute alian sencon.

Serĉu en "tekstaro.com" la esprimon "**tuj antaŭ**", kaj vi trovos ekzemplojn, kaj lokajn kaj tempajn.

Comment: Do *fari tuj antaŭ ol* kaj *fari tuj, antaŭ ol* havas diferencajn signifojn? Ĝenas min, ke oni uzus *tuj* por relativa pasinteco. Kion vi opinias pri *ĵus de kiam...*?

Comment: Vi pravas, ke eblas alia senco, se oni komprenas "tuj" kaj "antaŭ ol..." kiel apartajn komplementojn (anstataŭ kompreni "tuj" kiel modifilon de "antaŭ ol..."). La samo validas por "ĝuste antaŭ ol...", kiu estas iom analoge dusenca.

Por "ĵus antaŭ ol..." eblas (laŭ mi) nur tia disa senco: apartaj "ĵus" kaj "antaŭ ol...".

Pri "ĵus de kiam" mi hezitas. Ŝajnas, ke tio donas tute tute alian sencon. Ĉu vi povas doni kompletan ekzemplon?

Comment: Ekz. *Matildo eliris ĵus de kiam eniris Viktoro, do ŝi ne vidis lin* kontraŭ *Matildo eliris tuj [de] kiam eniris Viktoro, kaj li ekkoleris*. Ĉagrene, mia daŭra supozo estis ke *tuj post* kaj *ĵus antaŭ* estas simetriaj.

Comment: La unua versio, kun "ĵus de kiam", estas apenaŭ komprenebla. Vi kredeble volas "Matildo eliris tuj post kiam eniris Viktoro".

Comment: Do vi kredas, ke simple ne eblas uzi *ĵus* iamaniere por diri *Matildo eliris, tuj antaŭ ol eniris Viktoro* (jen la celo de la unua—miaj du ekzemploj certe ne celas la samon)?

Comment: Serĉu en la Tekstaro la esprimon "\bĵus antaŭ\b" kaj vi trovos dekduon da perfekte bonaj kaj seneraraj ekzemploj, unu el ili eĉ de la tipo "ĵus antaŭ ol".

Comment: La vorto "ĵus" estas ne malofte uzata erare por montri precizecon tempan, kvantan aŭ alian, precipe de Germanoj, ĉar la Germana vorto "gerade" signifas kaj "ĵus", kaj "ĝuste" (en tia preciziga senco).

Tial estas kelkaj neimitindaj aperoj de "ĵus antaŭ" en la Tekstaro. Oni trovas tie ankaŭ kelkajn "ĵus tiam", "ĵus en tiu momento", "ĵus tiom" k.s., kaj eĉ unu "ĵus post"! En bona Esperanto oni uzu "tuj" aŭ "ĝuste" por tiu senco.

Comment: Sed se *tuj post* ("post momento post kiam") akcepteblas, kial ne *ĵus antaŭ*? Kio estas la motivo de la malsimetrio?

Comment: Mi konsentaa kun Bertilo pri malĝusteco  de la sufiĉe ofta uzo de _ĵus_ anstataŭ _ĝuste_, do kiel ia tempa precizigilo. Sed tio neniel ŝanĝas mian opinion, ke ĉiuj Tekstaro-ekzemploj kun _ĵus antaŭ_ estas perfekte bonaj. Mi ne pova atribui al tia _ĵus_ ian "precizigan sencon", ĝi pli-malpli egalas _momenton_, kiam temas pri antaŭtempeco de io. Simile, _tuj post_ estas proksimume egala al _momenton post_, _senprokraste post_. Eble iuj lingvoj donas neimitindajn modelojn por la simplaj Esperantaj vortoj.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend *tuj antaŭ ol* in this case. Sentences with this phrase are fairly common.

*Tuj antaŭ ol ili volis komenci, venis la inspektoro*

Examples with *ĵus antaŭ ol* are harder to find, and the way it's defined in PMEG and PIV don't leave it open to follow *ĵus* with *antaŭ*.

According to PMEG: *“antaŭ tre mallonga tempo, antaŭ momento”*

According to PIV: *«momenton antaŭ nun» aŭ «antaŭ tiam»*

Add the word *antaŭ* to the end of either definition and it does't make sense. Also note that the examples given in both places of *ĵus* always show it as a free-standing word, while the examples of *tuj* are quite often followed by a preposition.

Comment: Could the person who voted this answer down provide some feedback on how the answer could be made better?

Comment: Mi emas konsenti ke "ĵus" eble estas la malplej bona elekto, pro la difino de la vorto "antaŭ tre mallonga tempo". Estus strange diri "Mi komprenis, antaŭ tre mallonga tempo antaŭ ol vi respondis".

Answer (score 3):

You want ***ĵus***.

*Ĵus* means a moment before, while *tuj* means a moment after (or without delay). So *tuj* cannot be attached to *antaŭ*; it must refer to the first verb.

> *Mi komprenis tuj antaŭ ol vi respondis.* I understood straightaway, before you replied.
>
> *Mi komprenis ĵus antaŭ ol vi respondis.* I understood just before you answered.

You could say *ekkomprenis* but it isn't necessary here because the time sequence is given explicitly.

*Tuj* can also be used figuratively, but *ĵus* cannot.

EDIT: This answer turned out to be unexpectedly controversial, but I don't feel I understand the counterarguments well enough yet to revise it, and in any case googling reveals plenty of examples of both being used for *just before* by competent authors. So, I'm stuck. It seems you just have to be careful about your word order, and use plenty of commas.

Comment: This contains an error. Another definition of *tuj* has to do with proximity. In that case *tuj antaŭ ol vi respondis* can indeed mean "right before you answered."

Comment: Extending *tuj* to mean *ĵus* is bad practice.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for that? Esperanto is full of examples of spacial metaphors being used to express time. "Antaux" is one of them. "Tuj antaux" is no different. I was unable to find any reference book (I checked PIV and PMEG) which referenced the expression "jxus antaux" as a good expression to ues.

Comment: But those works (and PAG also) are the basis of my opinion! PMEG says that *tuj* means *sen prokrasto* (in time) or *tute proksime* (in space). It allows that spatial and temporal uses can mix, but not that they can be contradictory, which would be very confusing. I tend to avoid *ĵus kiam* because it is often used wrongly for *ĝuste kiam*. Other than that, the clear counterpart to *tuj post* is *ĵus antaŭ* and I don't really understand your objection to it.

Comment: The article in PMEG about tuj - speaks of a "loka tuj" which is sometimes used with a temporal sense. It gives the the example of "tuj post".

Comment: *Ĵusdirite*: they can *mix*. It doesn't say that they can *contradict*. In the example, the travelling companion follows *after* the princess.

Comment: I will add a clarification about this to my answer. In the meanwhile, I've asked Bertilo if he'd be willing to clarify the intended meaning in PMEG.

Answer (score 1):

Mi mem sekvas la difinojn

- tuj = post mallongega tempo, sen prokrasto (post tiu momento)
- ĵus = antaŭ tre mallonga tempo, je tre proksima antaŭa tempo

kaj vortaroj ŝajnas samopinii.

Tial mi opinias, ke neniel eblas "tuj antaŭ tagmezo", kaj mi dirus nur

- _Mi (ek)komprenis ĵus antaŭ via respondo.
  Kiel vi mem konstatis, oni povas trovi ambaŭ esprimojn *tuj antaŭ ol* kaj *ĵus antaŭ ol*. *Tuj antaŭ*, sen *ol*, estas eĉ tre ofta, ĉar *tuj* (sed ne *ĵus*) havas ankaŭ la lokan signifon ‘tute proksime’, ekzemple: *Ŝi staris tuj antaŭ la pordo.*

Ŝajnas, ke eĉ bonaj aŭtoroj iam skribas "tuj antaŭ ol". Eble tio okazas pro alilingvaj vortoj. Mi pensas, ke ekzemple en la Angla oni povas bone diri *immediately before you answered* (sed eble ne *at once before you answered*).

Do, oni certe ne povas multe riproĉi vin, se vi skribas "*tuj antaŭ ol vi respondis*", sed laŭ mia opinio tio signifus *"momenton post antaŭ ol vi respondis"*. Sed ja eblas diri: *Vi respondis tuj post kiam mi ekkomprenis*.

Comment: Kion vi opinias pri traduki la respondon al la angla sub la originalo? Se vi ne volas eble iu alia povus

Comment: Jes, tio estus bona ideo. Mi fakte eĉ ne rimarkis, kiun lingvon la demandinto uzis – estis tiom da Esperantaj frazoj en ĝi. Ĝuste nun mi ne havas tempon por tio, sed mi pensis pliampleksigi la respondon per ekzemploj, ĉar en posta respondo venis la aserto "Examples with _ĵus antaŭ ol_ are harder to find",

Comment: *Tuj antaux* means "directly in front of." This is well attested. The question is whether the expression is limited to literal usage describing spacial relationships, or whether it can apply to other kinds of relationships that use spacial metaphors, such as expressions of time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you don't need to translate *before* to *antaŭ*, then it gets easy:

I understood -> Mi komprenis

you answered -> vi respondis

just before -> ĵus.

Now just put them in the right order because *ĵus* goes in front of the verb, and add a correlative to link the sentences:

Mi ĵus komprenis, kiam vi respondis.